# Extend AngularJS $resource to map to Rails RESTful Routes (particularly $save to create AND update)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, rest, angularjs

I'd like to map the default AngularJS $resource actions:

```
  'get':    {method:'GET'}
  'save':   {method:'POST'}
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'}
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
```

to these 5 Rails RESTful routes:

```
  'show':   {method:'GET'}                 -> get
  'create': {method:'POST'}                -> save
  'update': {method:'PUT'}                 -> save
  'index':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}   -> query
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'}              -> remove or delete
```

Everything maps well except for `save`. It works on `create` as a `POST` request. But I'd like to change it to a `PUT` request when I'm saving a resource that has an `id != null`

```
# This factory needs a smarter $save() method
myServices.factory 'Message', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    Message = $resource "api/users/:user_id/messages/:id",
        user_id: '@user_id'
        id: '@id'
    ,
        # update should not be needed
        update:
            method: 'PUT'

    Message
]


myApp.controller "UsersShowCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "User", "Message", ($scope, $routeParams, User, Message) ->
    $scope.user = User.get({id: $routeParams.user_id})
    $scope.myMessage = new Message {user_id: $routeParams.user_id}

    $scope.submitMyMessage = ->
        # This should just be:
        # $scope.myMessage.$save()
        # rather than:
        unless $scope.myMessage.id?
            $scope.myMessage.$save()
        else
            $scope.myMessage.$update()

]
```

I would ultimately like to modify the the submitted params as well so that I can namespace them to the default rails nested params i.e. `params[:message]` rather than attaching them directly to the root `params` string, but first I need to know how best to modify the the $resource.

Comment: can i ask what language is this? it's kinda interesting, you writing angular, but the way is more like the ruby you talked about... how it compile to js? does the browser know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, how about this save() method?

```
myServices.factory 'Message', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    Message = $resource "api/users/:user_id/messages/:id",
        user_id: '@user_id'
        id: '@id'
    ,
        # update should not be needed
        update:
            method: 'PUT'

    Message::save = ->
        if @id?
            @update()
        else
            @create()

    Message
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for one resource, but I'd prefer not to have to add it to every resource. I'd rather extend the $resource module to respond to this different api, but I don't understand javascript and Angular well enough to do it.